# python module not reading from dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Pokemon via (id) stored in a "poked.csv" file.  the program is running, but it's not recognizing the specified (id) - not sure if it's not recognizing there's a dictionary or if something else is going on..

here is my dictionary of key:values

```
from pokemon import *
from move import Move

pokemon_entries ={}

my_file=open("pokedex.csv", "r")
my_file.readline()
for line in my_file:
    pokedex_id, name, type1, type2, weight, height, move_name, move_power = line.strip().split(",")
    pokemon_entry={}
    pokemon_entry["pokedex_id"]=int(pokedex_id)
    pokemon_entry["name"]=name
    pokemon_entry["type1"]=type1
    pokemon_entry["type2"]=type2
    pokemon_entry["weight"]=float(weight)
    pokemon_entry["height"]=float(height)
    pokemon_entry["move"]=Move

    pokemon_entries[int(pokedex_id)]=pokemon_entry

my_file.close()
```

my csv has matching key:values for all the attributes referenced above.
her's the method I'm attempting to run:

```
def generate_pokemon(id):
    pokemon=Pokemon()
    if id in pokemon_entries.keys():
        name=pokemon_entries[id]["name"]
        type1=pokemon_entries[id]["type1"]
        type2=pokemon_entries[id]["type2"]
        cp=random.randint(10,500)    
        hp=random.randint(10, max(10,1.5*cp//10))
        weight=round(pokemon_entries[id]["weight"]*(1+0.5*random.uniform(-1,1)),2)
        height=round(pokemon_entries[id]["height"]*(1+0.5*random.uniform(-1,1)),2)
        sex=random.choice(["M","F"])
    else:
        print("Entered ID does not exist in Pokedex! A default pokemon will be created.")

    return pokemon
```

Regardless of the (id) I specify, I receive the "Entered ID does not exist..." message. I'm new to creating dictionaries and reading from files, so any help is appreciated. Yes, this is HW.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `pokemon_entries[int(pokedex_id)]=pokemon_entry` The key is an integer.  In your second code block, has `id` also been converted to an integer?  (2 is not equal to "2".)

Comment: I don't think it has - would I just need an id =int(id) line in the method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it' s just not reading from the csv file.. I'm not longer getting the "Entered ID does not exist..." message - but it's still not reading the values in the csv..